# Core Data: no index path for table cell being reused, Cells disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsindexpath

I am trying to make an app which save some entries in Core Data and also with an option to sync it online. What I want is that when the document is syncing, it has a different image on the cell's imageView and on the background, I send requests to get the unique IDs of all the synced documents. So, whenever the document is synced, its' imageView's image changes. So, far, I have done this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.syncedIds = NSMutableArray()
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tokenAndIds = NSMutableArray()


    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let authToken = prefs.valueForKey("authToken") as! String

    values["auth_code"] = "\(authToken)"

    self.checkSync()

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(6.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ReceiptsListViewController.checkSync), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier as String, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReceiptsViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    let entry: DiaryEntry = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DiaryEntry

    cell.configureCellForEntry(entry)
    cell.imageButton.tag = indexPath.row

    if (self.tableView.editing) {
        cell.imageButton.hidden = true
    } else {
        cell.imageButton.hidden = false
    }

    if (cell.syncImageView.image == UIImage(named: "syncing")) {

        let idString: String = "\(cell.idParam!)"
        tokenAndIds.addObject(idString)
    }



    if (syncedIds != nil) {
        for i in 0 ..< syncedIds.count {
            if (syncedIds[i] as! String == "\(cell.idParam!)") {

                print("Synced Ids are: \(syncedIds[i])")

                let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier as String, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReceiptsViewCell

                let entry: DiaryEntry = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DiaryEntry
                entry.sync = 2

                let coreDataStack: CoreDataStack = CoreDataStack.defaultStack
                coreDataStack.saveContext()

                cell1.configureCellForEntry(entry)

                self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                                  cell.syncImageView.image = UIImage(named: "sync")

            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func checkSync() {

    if (tokenAndIds != nil && tokenAndIds != []) {
        let idArray: NSMutableArray = tokenAndIds


        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://10.0.0.4:81/iphone/sync.php")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        values["idArray"] = idArray

        request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(values, options: [])

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (let data, let response, let error) in

            if let _ = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    if let parseJSON = json {


                        for (key, value) in parseJSON {

                            if (value as! String == "0") {
                                print(key)

                                self.syncedIds.addObject(key)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error is Here: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

But the problem is that when I get the response about all the synced IDs and then I go into another View and then come back to make the changes to the syncImageView, cells keep on disappearing and I also get this warning: "no indexpath for cell being reused." I know it is something to do with cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but what is it? Also, if I stop the app and re-run it, then, everything is fixed like imageView is changed and no cells disappear.

Comment: Don't make extensive computations with repeat loops in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (the view). According to the model-view-controller pattern perform computations in the controller, then put the results into the data source array (model) and then call `reloadData()` to refresh the UI (view).

Comment: It looks like `syncedIds` should be a dictionary, not an array, but your big problem is calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` from *inside* `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and there is no need to call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` twice - just get the cell and configure it as you need to

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried doing this without reloadRows and without dequeReusable.., but it gets worse.

Comment: That is hard to imagine.  You certainly don't need `cell1` - you can just use `cell` and if you store your synced Ids in a set you can get rid of the for loop and reloading a cell inside this function is the cause of the error message

Comment: Ok, 1st I understand, but the 2nd point, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am certain that I do need to get rid of dequeresuable which I have and also the loop which I am unable to figure out how.

Comment: You already have a cell instance in the variable `cell` - you can just modify it as required.  Nothing is reflected in the table view until you return the cell from this method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the async call within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  You need to get your code (outside of the tableView dataSource and delegate) and once you have your data fetched (and likely stored in some type of collection, like an Array), call reloadData() on your tableView and refresh the data.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` should be looking for existing data, not fetching the data.  `indexPath.row` is used to call your collection index and get the appropriate data.

By the time your async call is finished, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has already completed and the reference to the cell you are trying to update no longer exists (hence the error).

**TIP:**

Remember, after you get your data in a background thread, be sure to call reloadData() on the main thread

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking the same. I am thinking about parsing the entire table view seperately. Would that be a good idea. I will check the code in 1-2 days.